# Проблема со свайпом сайдбаров

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не могу разрешить проблему со свайпом сайдбаров: один открываю, потом закрываю -  открывается второй. Как быть?
Надо так: когда один открыл, ты должен его закрыть и тогда открывать другой.
[http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yvz5ynhx/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/yvz5ynhx/11/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebarLeft">
</div>
<div class="sidebarRight"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebarLeft{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60%;
}

.sidebarRight{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: -60%;   
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body')
        .on('swiperight', function(){    
            if (parseInt($('.sidebarRight').css('right')) >= 0) {
                $('.sidebarRight').animate({
                    right: '-60%'
                },200);
            } else {
                $('.sidebarLeft').animate({
                    left: '0%'
                },200);
            }
        })
        .on('swipeleft', function(){
            if (parseInt($('.sidebarLeft').css('left')) >= 0) {
                $('.sidebarLeft').animate({
                    left: '-60%'
                },200);
            } else {
                $('.sidebarRight').animate({
                    right: '0%'
                },200);
            }
        });
});
```